# Refreshing data using JSON

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I am attempting to refresh comments I have on a page every three seconds. However, the code I have isn't refreshing the comments, it is basically outputting the same set of comments I have every three seconds, but it isn't using the classes or img tag I have. It is outputting this every three seconds, over and over again.

[image]

Does anyone have any idea why the method I am using is outputting the same set of comments instead of checking for if there is a new one?

AJAX

```
function commentRetrieve(){

    $.ajax({ 
            url: "ajax-php/comment-retrieve.php",
            type: "get",
            success: function (data) {
            //  console.log(data);
                if (data == "Error!") {
                    alert("Unable to retrieve comment!");
                    alert(data);
                } else {
                    var array = JSON.parse(data);
                    $(array).each(function($value) {
                        if($('#comment-container').find('#comment-' + $value.id).length == 0) {
                            $('#comment-container').prepend($value.html);
                        }
                    });
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus + " | " + errorThrown);
                console.log("error"); //otherwise error if status code is other than 200.
            }
        });


}
setInterval(commentRetrieve, 3000);
```

PHP

```
if ($select_comments_stmt = $con->prepare($select_comments_sql)) {
            //$select_comments_stmt->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $select_comments_stmt->execute();
            $rows = $select_comments_stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            foreach ($rows as $row) {
                $comment_id = $row['id'];
                $comment_user_id = $row['user_id'];
                $comment_username = $row['username'];
                $home_comments = $row['comment'];
                $comment_date = $row['date'];
                $commenter_user_id = $row['user_id'];
                $commenter_img = $row['img'];
                $commenter_img = '<img class="home-comment-profile-pic" src=" '.$commenter_img.'">';
                if ($home_comments === NULL) {
                    echo 'No comments found.';
                } else {
                    $html = "";
                    $html .= '<div class="comment-post-box">';
                    $html .= $commenter_img;
                    $html .= '<div class="comment-post-username">'.$comment_username. '</div>';
                    $html .= '<div>'.$comment_date. '</div>';
                    $html .= '<div class="comment-post-text">'.$home_comments. '</div>';
                    $html .= '</div>';
                    $data = array('id' => $comment_id, 'html' => $html);
                    echo json_encode($data);
                }
            }
        } else {
            echo "Error!";
        }
```

Comment page, with initial `SELECT` query to load comments on page load.

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="comment-form">
            <textarea id="home_comment" name="comment" placeholder="Write a comment..." maxlength="1000" required></textarea><br>
            <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>">
            <input id="comment-button" name="submit" type="submit" value="Post">
        </form>
        <div id="comment-container">
<?php
$select_comments_sql = "
    SELECT c. *, p.user_id, p.img
    FROM home_comments AS c
    INNER JOIN (SELECT max(id) as id, user_id 
                FROM profile_img 
                GROUP BY user_id) PI
      on PI.user_id = c.user_id
    INNER JOIN profile_img p
      on PI.user_id = p.user_id
     and PI.id = p.id
    ORDER BY c.id DESC
";

  if ($select_comments_stmt = $con->prepare($select_comments_sql)) {
        $select_comments_stmt->execute();
        if (!$select_comments_stmt->errno) {
            //echo "error";
        }
        $select_comments_stmt->bind_result($comment_id, $comment_user_id, $comment_username, $home_comments, $comment_date, $commenter_user_id, $commenter_img);
    //var_dump($select_comments_stmt);  
        $comment_array = array();
        while ($select_comments_stmt->fetch()) {
            $comment_array[] = $comment_user_id;
            $comment_array[] = $comment_username;
            $comment_array[] = $home_comments;
            $comment_array[] = $comment_date;
            $comment_array[] = $commenter_user_id;
            $comment_array[] = $commenter_img;
            $commenter_img = '<img class="home-comment-profile-pic" src=" '.$commenter_img.'">';
            if ($home_comments === NULL) {
                echo 'No comments found.';
            } else {
                echo '<div class="comment-post-box">';
                echo $commenter_img;
                echo '<div class="comment-post-username">'.$comment_username. '</div>';
                echo '<div>'.$comment_date. '</div>';
                echo '<div class="comment-post-text">'.$home_comments. '</div>';
                echo '</div>';
            }
        }
  }
?>
        </div>
```

Comment: Where is the ajax code? Also it is better to only send json data and create the html view in ajax. The problem you get every time the same data is because you query 3 seconds the same data. You should add a where statement to get all id's after the last received comments.

Comment: I am using this with a SELECT query, so I do not have the data initially. The AJAX code is in my question.

Comment: I see only 3 times php code?

Comment: @Perry Sorry, it is now fixed.

Comment: You do not have a id set for your comments. That is why your ajax code is failing. Replace this: `echo '<div class="comment-post-box">';` with the following: `echo '<div class="comment-post-box" id="comment-'. $commend_id .'">';`

Comment: How would I make an id for that then?

Comment: Sorry, misread your comment. The change did not help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the following thing in your php code:

```
echo '<div class="comment-post-box">';
```

with the following:

```
echo '<div class="comment-post-box" id="comment-'. $comment_id .'">';
```

Also change this following in your ajax:

```
if($('#comment-container').find('#comment-' + $value.id).length == 0) {
```

To this:

```
if($('#comment-' + $value.id).length == 0) {
```

Since a id can be just used once on a page we don't care where it is set.

*Update 1*

Your json code is invalid, so we need to change your php code some bit:

So change this:

```
foreach ($rows as $row) {
            $comment_id = $row['id'];
            $comment_user_id = $row['user_id'];
            $comment_username = $row['username'];
            $home_comments = $row['comment'];
            $comment_date = $row['date'];
            $commenter_user_id = $row['user_id'];
            $commenter_img = $row['img'];
            $commenter_img = '<img class="home-comment-profile-pic" src=" '.$commenter_img.'">';
            if ($home_comments === NULL) {
                echo 'No comments found.';
            } else {
                $html = "";
                $html .= '<div class="comment-post-box">';
                $html .= $commenter_img;
                $html .= '<div class="comment-post-username">'.$comment_username. '</div>';
                $html .= '<div>'.$comment_date. '</div>';
                $html .= '<div class="comment-post-text">'.$home_comments. '</div>';
                $html .= '</div>';
                $data = array('id' => $comment_id, 'html' => $html);
                echo json_encode($data);
            }
        }
```

To this:

```
foreach ($rows as $row) {
            $comment_id = $row['id'];
            $comment_user_id = $row['user_id'];
            $comment_username = $row['username'];
            $home_comments = $row['comment'];
            $comment_date = $row['date'];
            $commenter_user_id = $row['user_id'];
            $commenter_img = $row['img'];
            $commenter_img = '<img class="home-comment-profile-pic" src=" '.$commenter_img.'">';
            if ($home_comments === NULL) {
                echo 'No comments found.';
            } else {
                $html = "";
                $html .= '<div class="comment-post-box">';
                $html .= $commenter_img;
                $html .= '<div class="comment-post-username">'.$comment_username. '</div>';
                $html .= '<div>'.$comment_date. '</div>';
                $html .= '<div class="comment-post-text">'.$home_comments. '</div>';
                $html .= '</div>';
                $data[] = array('id' => $comment_id, 'html' => $html);
            }
        }
                echo json_encode($data);
```

So we make just first a array with all comments so the output will be a correct json response to the client.

Update 2:

I have changed your each function some bit:

```
$(array).each(function(key, value) {
                        if($('#comment-' + value.id).length == 0) {
                            $('#comment-container').prepend(value.html);
                        }
                    });
```

Notice the `key,value` in the function.

After that it was working correctly, I noticed you have to change you comment-retrieve.php since the comments where appending multiple times. You create here your comment div, but without a id. So also change in this file you comment box to `echo '<div class="comment-post-box" id="comment-'. $comment_id .'">';` Then it should be working.

You can test it by inserting a new record on your database, or delete a comment in your browser by using web developer tools from your browser or a plugin like firebug.

Comment: I cannot tell this for sure as the error is still present and the same comments are still outputting definitively, but it appears it is saying that $comment_id is not defined.

Comment: @Paul my bad, I had comment with a d at the end but it should b t. I updated my answer. You only should change `commend` to `comment`.

Comment: It is not giving the undefined variable any longer, but still doing the initial problem.

Comment: If you want to see the site live, just let me know, it may help you better understand what it is doing

Comment: can you provide the link?

Comment: Sure. Go here and login. http://farleysharley.com/test-index ...username = test12 ... password = test12 .

Comment: You have disabled the timer, can you activate it?

Comment: Just changed it to that, except put one more closing } above the echo json. Same error it looks like.